# NSFetchedResultsController creating duplicate cells on top of each other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So I'm using NSFRC to populate my UITableView. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I load the information for each cell from Core Data using:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myProto"];
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

`configureCell` then fills 50% of the cell in by using tags, e.g.:

```
MyEntity *myEntity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
nameLabel.text = myEntity.entityName;
```

This continues for all the other labels and image views. While all this is happening a dictionary is populated with information from a server. The information is then used to fill in the remaining 50% of the cell, again in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. in `willDisplayCell`, I do some calculations that effect minor things like the colour of text, based on calculations done on both the information saved in Core Data and information downloaded from the internet. Also in `willDisplayCell` I do a check to see if all the information has been downloaded from the internet. If it has, I cycle through the fetched results and changes an `Attribute` called `sectionsSort` based on exactly the same calculations that were done earlier. So in other words, once the loading is complete the TableView does calculations to figure out what section a specific cell should go into. NSFRC then sorts the UITableView out putting everything into correct sections.

I understand that this procedure is a little iffy because we're setting sections after everything has been loaded. I've done my best to handle everything appropriately, e.g. I don't allow any interaction from the user while all this is going on and I only set the section info once everything has been downloaded from the internet. However, I've clearly not accounted for something as the NSFRC seems to be creating duplicate cells on top of each other. I can tell because on a couple of cells there's a semi-transparent background which becomes doubly strong from the overlapping. They seem to come and go depending on where you are in the TableView and it causes multiple glitches. I'm clearly using NSFRC wrong somewhere, but I just don't know where.

If you could help me diagnose this problem I'd greatly appreciate it.
Regards,
Mike

**UPDATE:** Think I've just found out a potential reason for this. On `viewDidAppear` I set the sections of every single entity. It seems that every time I save the entity NSFRC recreates the rows on screen. Is this a correct inference?

**UPDATE 2** It seems there's something more to it than that. The last 6 cells aren't even recognised by the NSFRC, even though they're displayed. When I press edit all the apps move to the right (as they should) except for the last 6. There's a whole load of weird behaviour going on. My NSLog in `willDisplayCell` seems to be going on and on lots of times, even when the TableView is not scrolling.

**UPDATE 3** Ok so my code to set the Section is definitely the problem. Just commented out all of it and it works fine. Here is how I set the section for each entity:

```
for (id i in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
    myEntity *myEntity = i;
    DownloadResult *downloadResult = [[DownloadResult alloc] init];
    downloadResult = [downloadResultsDictionary objectForKey:myEntity.entityName];

if (condition)
    {
        myEntity.sectionSort = @"2";

        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
            return;
        }
    } 
else if (...
```

There's clearly something wrong with the way I'm doing this as it's sending NSFRC into overdrive and causing multiple glitches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. Stupid mistake at the end of the day. I had forgotten to reload the TableView!

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: 5 years too late, but incase anyone else comes here. Either use NSFetchedResultsController or reloadData.  Doing a reloadData overwrites the work that the FRC did, also you lose the nice animations.